# Не понимаю как именно Retrofit парсит json с GSON и как с этим работать

Tags: java, android, retrofit, gson

Вот что я нагуглил про получению json данных по api(немного псевдокод)

```
    //тут как-бы ясно
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://site/api")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    //в api уже реализованный retrofit-ом метод из интерфеса
    DataInterface api = retrofit.create(DataInterface.class);

    //не совсем понял
    Call<List<MyModel>> call = api.getData();

    //это ок. обработка данных в новом потоке
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MyModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MyModel>> call, Response<List<MyModel>> response) {
            //если я правильно понял, тут приходит список объектов MyModel
            //уже заполненный данными??? каким образом?
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<MyModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            //обработка ошибки
        }
    });
```

А вот и DataInterface

```
    public interface DataInterface {
        @GET("apiUri")
        Call<List<MyModel>> getData();
    }
```

Насколько я понял MyModel это POJO, но в примерах этот объект имел только приватные свойства и геттеры.
Тогда что приходит в onResponse?

Помогите пожалуйста понять всю эту магию и как с этим работать. Спасибо.

Comment: В `onResponse` происходит только то, что вы напишете. А под капотом запроса происходит парсинг ответа с помощью указанного конвертера. Конвертер, в свою очередь - это связующая оболочка для соответствующей библиотеки, в данном случае [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson). Чтобы понять как происходит парсинг - почитайте про саму библиотеку. В кратце: ей передаётся тип POJO класса, она работает с ним через `reflection` - создаёт экземпляр, читает json, ищет в POJO соответствующие поля по именам и аннотациям и присваивает им значения из json

Comment: @woesss присваивает значения из json даже если поля private?

Comment: Через геттеры. Основной принцп джавы

Comment: @СергейО, да, есть такой замечательный пакет `java.lang.reflect` - почитайте на досуге о его возможностях. `Gson` использует его для доступа к полям, так как иным способом получить список и имена полей класса невозможно. Доступ к приватным членам класса тоже не проблема, по крайней мере для ваших самописных, а не системных.

Comment: Возьмите JSON в виде текста, GSON и ваш POJO и напишите пару тестов. Без Retrofit. Сразу понятнее станет. Это проблема большинства примеров о Retrofit из сети, там всегда Retrofit и GSON в одной куче. На самом деле они абсолютно независимы друг от друга.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja понял, сделаю